# SwitchUserFilter not working in Spring security when used with Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am having a problem with SwitchUserFilter in Spring security. I have following configuration:

```
<bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg name="searchBase" value=""/>
    <constructor-arg name="searchFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
    <constructor-arg name="contextSource" ref="ldapContext"/>
</bean>

<security:ldap-server id="ldapContext" url="ldap://xxxxxxx"/>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticator">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="ldapContext" />
            <property name="userSearch" ref="ldapUserSearch" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="authoritiesPopulator" ref="dbLDAPAuthPopulator" />
</bean>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And the corresponding SwitchUserFilter bean is created as:

```
SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter = new SwitchUserFilter();
switchUserFilter.setUserDetailsService(ldapUserDetailsService);
switchUserFilter.setTargetUrl("/");
switchUserFilter.setSwitchUserUrl("/impersonate");
switchUserFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
switchUserFilter.setExitUserUrl("/unimpersonate");
```

When I go to the url "/impersonate" the user gets impersonated properly. However when the redirect is send to the target url i.e. "/" the user is again authenticated using basic auth.

I had a look at the code of both the SwitchUserFilter and BasicAuthenticationFilter and seems that SU will not work with basic auth.

This is what happens:

1. When the /impersonate?username=xyz url is called it goes to SwitchUserFilter which gets the details of xyz user from the ldap and it then sets the securitycontext in the session. Code snippet is as follows:

   if (requiresSwitchUser(request)) {
   // if set, attempt switch and store original
           try {
               Authentication targetUser = attemptSwitchUser(request);

   ```
           // update the current context to the new target user
           SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(targetUser);

           // redirect to target url
           successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, targetUser);
       } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
           logger.debug("Switch User failed", e);
           failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, e);
       }

       return;
   ```
2. So in the SecurityContext you have information about xyz user.
3. Then when it redirects to target url i.e. "/" `basicAuthenticationFilter` is called which checks whether the user is authenticated.  Code snippet:

Authentication existingAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

```
    if(existingAuth == null || !existingAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }

    // Limit username comparison to providers which use usernames (ie UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)
    // (see SEC-348)

    if (existingAuth instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken && !existingAuth.getName().equals(username)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Handle unusual condition where an AnonymousAuthenticationToken is already present
    // This shouldn't happen very often, as BasicProcessingFitler is meant to be earlier in the filter
    // chain than AnonymousAuthenticationFilter. Nevertheless, presence of both an AnonymousAuthenticationToken
    // together with a BASIC authentication request header should indicate reauthentication using the
    // BASIC protocol is desirable. This behaviour is also consistent with that provided by form and digest,
    // both of which force re-authentication if the respective header is detected (and in doing so replace
    // any existing AnonymousAuthenticationToken). See SEC-610.
    if (existingAuth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

4. As you can see it checks `existingAuth.getName().equals(username))` which in this case it is xyz. However logged in user is different so the filter again authenticates the user and all the work done by SwitchUserFilter is overridden.

Is their any way to solve this issue? Can I override the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is quite old, however should anyone come across it the answer is still valid today.  You don't show your `<http />` stanzas for Spring Security but you need to ensure that the role granted by impersonation is the same role (`authority`) required to bypass authentication at `/*`.  If it's not then yes, you will be asked to authenticate.

You can specify custom authorities to be granted on impersonation by implementing an extension of `SwitchUserAuthorityChanger` and passing a reference of it to `SwitchUserFilter`.